# Does a polynomial that's bounded below have a global minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, polynomials, maxima-minima

Must a polynomial function $f \in \mathbb{R}[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ that's lower bounded by some $\lambda \in \mathbb{R}$ have a global minimum over $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Something for your perusal: http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?aid=4903004

Comment: ...and also http://www.jstor.org/stable/2324459

Answer (score 36, accepted):

No.  The polynomial $f(x, y) = (1 - xy)^2 + x^2$ is bounded below by $0$, cannot actually take the value $0$, but can take the value $\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.  I learned this example from [Richard Dore](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/23478/examples-of-common-false-beliefs-in-mathematics/30979#30979) on MO.

Answer (score 1):

@Agusti Roig. $f$ has no critical points in the interior of the disc, so you have to look for the minimum at the unit circle. One way would be to parametrize $x=\cos\theta, y=\sin\theta$, and minimize.